Словоерс уместен со словами "господин", "госпожа"?
Употреблялись ли раньше "господин-с" и "госпожа-с"?
Каковы вообще правила использования словоерса?

• Из словаря-справочника «Непростые слова»:
словоер, словоерик, словоерс — название звука с (написание — съ), прибавлявшегося в старину к концу слов в знак почтения к собеседнику (например: Да-съ, Нет-съ); от названия сочетания букв -съ: с — "слово" и ъ — "ер", "ерик".
Частица с (съ) представляет собой сокращение обращения сударь, государь.
• Теоретически словоерс может добавляться к любому значимому слову:
штабс-капитан-с, что-с, ждём-с, убили-с, имею-с, ну-с, так-с, доволен-с, приятно-с, они-с...
• Со словами сударь (сударыня) и государь (государыня) не употребляется из-за тавтологичности.
• Думаю, что со словами господин и госпожа тоже не используется (господин-сударь? госпожа-сударыня?).
Разве что у Достоевского нашлись два примера с откровенным, демонстративным самоунижением:

Но она стала на своем и досказала: по ее словам, она уже была здесь летом с одною «очень благородною госпожой-с» из города и тоже заночевали, пока пароход не приходил, целых даже два дня-с, и что такого горя натерпелись, что вспомнить страшно. «Вот вы, Степан Трофимович, изволили спросить эту комнату для одного себя-с… Я только потому, чтобы предупредить-с… <...> Так за особую комнату и за то, что вы вот спросили у них обедать-с, и за обиду всем проезжим они столько с вас потребуют, что и в столицах не слыхано-с…» ["Бесы"]


— Как это так на кой ляд-с? — А наследство-то-с? — ядовито и как-то даже отмстительно подхватил Смердяков. — Ведь вам тогда после родителя вашего на каждого из трех братцев без малого по сорока тысяч могло прийтись, а может, и того больше-с, а женись тогда Федор Павлович на этой самой госпоже-с, Аграфене Александровне, так уж та весь бы капитал тотчас же после венца на себя перевела, ибо они очень не глупые-с, так что вам всем троим братцам и двух рублей не досталось бы после родителя. А много ль тогда до венца-то оставалось? Один волосок-с: стоило этой барыне вот так только мизинчиком пред ними сделать, и они бы тотчас в церковь за ними высуня язык побежали.
<...>
— Как же вам на них не рассчитывать было-с; ведь убей они, то тогда всех прав дворянства лишатся, чинов и имущества, и в ссылку пойдут-с. Так ведь тогда ихняя часть-с после родителя вам с братцем Алексеем Федоровичем останется, поровну-с, значит, уже не по сороку, а по шестидесяти тысяч вам пришлось бы каждому-с. Это вы на Дмитрия Федоровича беспременно тогда рассчитывали! ["Братья Карамазовы"]

• Интересен с точки зрения "благоговения, сладости и почтительной кислоты" пример из рассказа Чехова "Толстый и тонкий":

— Я, ваше превосходительство... Очень приятно-с! Друг, можно сказать, детства и вдруг вышли в такие вельможи-с! Хи-хи-с.
— Ну, полно! — поморщился толстый. — Для чего этот тон? Мы с тобой друзья детства — и к чему тут это чинопочитание!
— Помилуйте... Что вы-с... — захихикал тонкий, еще более съеживаясь. — Милостивое внимание вашего превосходительства... вроде как бы живительной влаги...

• Подробнее: О словоерсе, извольте-с (по материалам книги Л. Успенского "Слово о словах").

Фактически логической ошибкой словоерс со словом "господин(-жа)" считаться не будет. Неграмотностью быть может. Но в том случае, для которого я информацию ищу демонстративное самоунижение как раз кстати будет.

Запретов, конечно же, нет. И Достоевский, думаю, делает это умышленно, не случайно. А других примеров мне не удалось найти.

Спасибо за ответ!
